# Broadcasting and scanning BLE devices simultaneously

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, proximity, scanning

As I understand it, Bluetooth in general (and hence BLE) uses a "client-server" model. A BT device is either broadcasting as a beacon or searching for them.

Is it possible to have a pair of BT devices operate as peers?

For example, make two devices (say smartphones) work both as scanning and receiving connections at the same time (preferably in background), for proximity-based app's purposes.

Comment: Another approach would be Google nearby api. Have you looked into that? Or you really want Bluetooth?

Comment: @The_Martian I have, but, as far as I understand, technically one of them anyway should be a "host" (either beacon or publisher) and second one a "client" (subscriber). And there is a restriction for background broadcasting (it is said background scanning is allowed for BLE which suits me perfectly) when the screen is off. I might be mistaking in my comprehension of how it works though. I'd be much obliged if someone tells me how Nearby actually can perform needed actions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes since Bluetooth 4.1 devices may be in multiple states at the same time. Most newer smartphones support that.